# AHK Button to run 'alt+tab' and ends when a window is picked

Tags: tabs, autohotkey, rainmeter, alt-key

I'm trying to code a button (rainmeter) that runs an AHK script for <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to prompt the Task Window and ends when I pick one. So far I've come up with this:

```
#NoTrayIcon
#InstallKeybdHook 
#InstallMouseHook 
Send, !{Tab}
KeyIsDown :=
GetKeyState (LButton,P)
return
ifEqual, KeyIsDown, 1
Exit
```

Comment: autohotkey kept running and I couldn't use the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Windows 7/10:**

Ctrl+Alt+Tab prompts the Task Window.

```
Send {Ctrl down}{Alt down}{Tab}{Alt up}{Ctrl up}
```

**Windows 8:**

```
Run %A_AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\Window Switcher.lnk
```